# What does " 존녜... 아입니꺼..." mean?

Tags: translation

A boy commented on my post  존녜... 아입니꺼... But I don't really know what it means. I tried to look it up but every translator says something different.

Answer (score 3):

"How beautiful/pretty you are." spoken in Pusan dialect + slang.

> 존녜... 아입니꺼...

- `존녜`; [`존예`](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3622671): `Extreme beauty`
- `아입니꺼`; `아입니까`: `Don’t you` / `Isn’t it`
- `...`: What implies that the speaker is being funny.

In standard language the sentence would be written as follows:

> 너무 예쁜 거 아닙니까

Comment: I have a couple of questions on this answer: Is it *Busan* dialect rather than Gyeongsang dialect? Isn't it a stretch to say that the ellipsis implies the speaker's *being funny*?

Comment: @Klmo That’s a valid point. Although, I doubt if I could ever provide complete rationale behind it other than just "that’s how it sounds to me".

Comment: `Is it Busan dialect rather than Gyeongsang dialect?` - While it does make sense either way, I get kindof feeling that it’s something ala 경남 방언. There are slight differences between 경남 and 경북 dialects: "-다이가"라든가, "아이가", "아입니꺼" 같은 말은 정확히는 동남방언인데, 개인적인 경험으로 미루어 봤을 때는 경북보다는 부산이나 울산쪽 말인 것 같습니다. 물론 대구나 경북에서도 쓰는 말이기는 하지만 단어를 들었을 때 느낌이 있잖아요. "안카나", "안캅니꺼"였으면 경북 사투리 이미지인데 "아입니꺼"는 부산 말이라는 느낌이 먼저 옵니다. 완벽한 예시는 아니지만 유머 사이트에 경남 vs 경북 방언 이야기가 있어서 링크 걸어 봅니다. [#Link](https://m.fmkorea.com/index.php?document_srl=2984702727&mid=humor&cpage=5) So that was my ground for calling it Pusan dialect.

Comment: `Isn't it a stretch to say that the ellipsis implies the speaker's being funny?` - In given context that’s how it came to me and I just had nothing else to define it. If it doesn’t mean what I thought it does, how would you say about why the writer added `...` in the sentence and what it really means? (Just curious)

Comment: Although 우리말샘 says that -ㅂ니꺼 is used in 경남, [this](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%8F%99%EB%82%A8%20%EB%B0%A9%EC%96%B8/%EC%83%81%EB%8C%80%20%EB%86%92%EC%9E%84%EB%B2%95) says "하이소체는 **경북 북부·동부를 제외한 경상도 전역**에 걸쳐 쓰이는 매우높임 존댓말..." and [this](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0016323) says "-음·심니까(경상남도 서남)-음·심니꺼(경상남도 서남 및 중부, 경상북도 중남동 내륙)...." Thus, it would be better to say that 아입니꺼 is Gyeongsang dialect to include not only Busan but also other regions.

Comment: This might not relate to the question, but I have found that 아이다 alone is used [in various regions](https://opendict.korean.go.kr/dictionary/view?sense_no=216953), and I have seen an example saying "칠팔 년 됐다 안캅니꺼" in 전라북도 방언사전. I find this interesting. // Regarding the ellipsis, I suppose it is like a pause or break indicating that he is overwhelmed in that he does not say such a short sentence at once. Or it might show his [hesitation](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=111174) or shyness in saying something to others. This is just my interpretation.